# Other than MtGox, what APIs are out there, which implement WebSockets as their transport mechanism?

Tags: api, html, websocket

I am looking to start working with some WebSockets and would like to create a few examples using some existing WebSocket APIs out there.

Do you know of any other ones that are nice other than MtGox's streaming API for Bitcoin?

Comment: Probably worth clarifying that you are looking for APIs that let you connect over WebSockets. You are not looking for WebSocket client or server implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSift have a WebSocket API:
http://support.datasift.com/help/kb/rest-api/websocket-streaming

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the websockets api prototype at [html5 labs](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info)?

Comment: I was looking for something more along the lines of what BitCoin has put out:  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API#Websocket_API

Comment: @ChrisChing I think the question is asking for APIs which offer WebSockets as their transport mechanism. Not WebSocket client implementations.